# Using a font from extrafont in grid.draw

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts, gtable

Say I have a dataset like this:

```
dat <- data.frame
  text = c(
    "It made me feel very positive to brand X", 
    "It was clear and easy to understand",
    "I didn't like it al all"),
  value=runif(3)
)
```

I can plot it in ggplot using can the *TradeGothic LT CondEighteen* font from the `extrafonts` package:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(text, value)) + 
     geom_bar(stat="identity") +
     coord_flip() +
     labs(title="     Do you agree with the following statements?")+
     theme_bw(16)+
     theme(text=element_text(family="TradeGothic LT CondEighteen"))

ggsave('plot.pdf', plot = plot,  path = "/Users/jacobdeecurtis/Desktop")
```

[image]

But when I use `ggplot_gtable` on the plot:

```
gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(plot))
gt$layout[which(gt$layout$name == "title"), c("l", "r")] <- c(1,         max(gt$layout$r))
grid::grid.draw(plot)

ggsave('plot.pdf', plot = plot,  path = "/Users/jacobdeecurtis/Desktop")
```

I get an error once I run the grid.draw function. The error is:

```
Error in grid.Call(L_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
  polygon edge not found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In grid.Call(L_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  no font could be found for family "TradeGothic LT CondEighteen"...
```

I don't get the error when I don't use the *TradeGothic LT CondEighteen* font.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try `"TradeGothic LT CondEighteen"`

Comment: Interesting. Isn't that what I tried? How is it different?

Comment: DId you do `extrafont::loadfonts()`?

Comment: Yeah, I did. And, I mean, the font works. It's only when I try to use grid.draw() with it that it breaks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I, uh, "just happened to have" a copy of this font and did the `extrafont::font_import()` dance and got your error. But, upon further inspection:

```
library(purrr)

loadfonts()

pdfFonts() %>% 
  map_chr("family") %>% 
  keep(~grepl(".*Trade.*", .))
## [1] "TradeGothic LT CondEighteen"
```

it seems the PDF device wants this name.

While R has a host of awesomeness, the way it deals with fonts is about as nuanced and friendly and usable as a lizard crow (#atla).

**UPDATE**

Complete example (without the broken `data.frame` creation code and referencing `plot` vs `p` and actually `grid.draw()`ing `gt` vs `plot` or `p` after modifying the ggplot gtable:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(extrafont)

dat <- data.frame(
  text = c(
    "It made me feel very positive to brand X", 
    "It was clear and easy to understand",
    "I didn't like it al all"),
  value=runif(3)
)

p <- ggplot(dat, aes(text, value)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(title="     Do you agree with the following statements?")+
  theme_bw(16)+
  theme(text=element_text(family="TradeGothic LT CondEighteen"))

loadfonts()

ggsave('plot.pdf', plot=p,  path="~/Desktop")
```

That ^^ part makes the following PDF (exported from Preview as a PNG):

[image]

```
gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))
gt$layout[which(gt$layout$name == "title"), c("l", "r")] <- c(1, max(gt$layout$r))

pdf("~/Desktop/plot.pdf")
grid::grid.draw(gt)
dev.off()
```

That ^^ part makes the following PDF (exported from Preview as a PNG):

[image]

```
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(text, value)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(title="     Do you agree with the following statements?")+
  theme_bw(16)+
  theme(text=element_text(family="TradeGothicLT-CondEighteen"))

gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))
gt$layout[which(gt$layout$name == "title"), c("l", "r")] <- c(1, max(gt$layout$r))

grid::grid.draw(gt)
```

Here's a screen grab from RStudio (with bits of RStudio UI included to show it's in an RStudio graphics device):

[image]

It's sad that we have to do this (change naming conventions for the font so various bits of R presentation code can pick the right one) but that's the current state of fonts in R.

I generate content for research reports for my company and separate theme code for screen (during development) and production PDF generation (for final output handoff to the creative team). It's a frustrating crutch, but it works.